# Is there an easy way to select the side of a disk-shaped object?

Tags: selection-tools, select

I have downloaded a few models from a site that the presenter in a YouTube tutorial mentioned. The ZIP files contained several formats like 3DS, but since Blender seems to understand only "obj", I used that format. The problem is all models I downloaded from that site are one giant object without any texture. That is, a table is one object, and a chair is one object.

So, I think I need to select a logical part of the object and apply different textures. The presenter seems to have applied a metal texture to the side of the table and a wooden texture to the top surface, but he did not explain that part. So, I am not sure how to select the side of the desk object.

Other than manually clicking all the faces on the side, is there an easier way to select the side of a disk-shaped object?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Face select mode you can select areas bounded by seams.

At some time or another you are probably going to have to UV unwrap your models to add "image" textures so why not start now :)

Once the seams have been added then you can select individual areas bounded by seams with the L key. see screenshots below

[image]

Comment: ..which also effectively stashes the selection for re-use.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the geometry, you'd be able to use *Loop Select*.

You can do this by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking LMB to select. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> tells blender to not clear the previous selection, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> enables *Loop Select.*

Things to note: if you click near the top/bottom of one of the faces, Blender will *Loop Select* in the vertical direction. Clicking on the left/right sides will *Loop Select* in the horizontal direction.

PS: This is also one of the reasons why having a good topology in your model is emphasized. Messy topology can block you from *Loop Selecting*, adding *Loop Cuts* etc., severely slowing down your workflow.

Note that the gif has been sped up a bit for the sake of not being too large to upload.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help and efforts. Actually, I knew alt + shift + click, but the side is actually rounded at the edges so the faces were too many and short that it was not easy to click them one by one. I tried, but I kept mis-selecting wrong faces/edges. I did not write it in the OP, but ideally I wanted to select only the top/bottom edges of the side, and select all faces in between, which is what the other answer explained.